# Importing asset bundle from web server in Android mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, augmented-reality, assetbundle

In Unity, I am creating an asset bundle and am loading that assets from server and am running that app in Android.  Now the problem was asset bundle can't be loaded in Android device, but it was loaded in Editor. Can anyone give me a suggestion to load assets bundle in Android?

Comment: Do a research before posting.  Google "load asset bundles on Android". There are just many posts for this.

Comment: The assetbundles for android should be build differently, the same dosen't work with all platforms. Consider building seperate assetbundles for different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build assetbundles according to the platform you're using.
[Check this link for Assetbundles buildtarget](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Building.html)

Change the `BuildTarget.TargetPlatform`[Check the build targets here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildTarget.html)

Comment: thanks for your help,rohankad . as well as whatever you said i tried, but did't get any changes in that!  do you have any other suggestion to load 3d model dynamically from the server at runtime in andriod mobile

Answer (score 0):

I created assetbundles using this code

```
public class creatinassets : MonoBehaviour {

[MenuItem ("Assets/Build AssetBundles")]
static void BulidAllAssetBundles()
{
    BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles("Assets/Asset bundles",BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, BuildTarget.Android );
}
```

I loaded the bundle using following code

```
public class loading : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject cub;
public WWW www;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine ("Downloadobject");
}   
IEnumerator Downloadobject()
{
    www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload  ("http://192.168.1.126/gopinath/AssetBundles/light",3);// light= Assetbundlename
    yield return www;

    AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
    if (bundle == null) {
        Debug.Log ("error loading www");
    } else {

         cub = (GameObject)bundle.LoadAsset ("lamp"); //lamp = Assetname   
        Instantiate (cub);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: check here rohankad

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have posted, the problem seems to be with the download. Check for www errors. Also check the link from your phone's browser.

```
  if(www.error)
  {
   Debug.Log(www.error)
  }
```